# Embed a view using code Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am writing a module and need to include a view in the code, I am doing the same approach as in this tutorial and looked every where online, everyone seems to using this same approach but it not working for me. Can anybody add to it as to why this approach might not be working. Link to tutorial is : https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/howto-best-practices-for-embedding-views-code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you can provide a little more detail about what you've done (actual code) and what is happening (displayed or logged errors etc) it'll be easier for people to be helpful.  The tutorial appears to be mostly correct but quite old (it uses views 2 but you should be using views 3 these days), so the fast answer is: find a newer one. To be more useful we'd need more information.

Comment: Thank you @acrosman for your response, I edited it to use views 3, I am doing everything locally so not able to provide a link, I will soon copy and paste my code and look into drupal watchdog for any errors, so you can have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use views_get_view() to grab a view anywhere.

```
$view = views_get_view('<view machine name>');
```

I have a larger example here: https://snippetbox.xyz/9eb54a2a1f52dc1f5d42/

Comment: Sorry, I think title of my question is bit misleading, if you can read the description, you will see that is not what I am asking. I am creating a module and exporting a view in the code so that when that module gets enabled, view gets created.